# How to link a div with an id to an anchor link with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<div>` with the ID “work1acc.” My goal is to link it to an anchor (#work1)—a section on my website. I’ve attempted to use code, but unfortunately, it’s not functioning as an anchor link. Here’s the code snippet I’ve tried:

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('work1acc').addEventListener('click', function() {
    location.href = '#work1';`
});
```

AI-generated code. Review and use carefully. More info on FAQ.
If anyone can provide assistance, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You have an extra backtick in your code which will be causing a syntax error. Check the console. Also - making a non-clickable element in to a clickable one is not good practice. Use an `a` element and set its `href`. Then you don't need any JS logic at all, as you get this behaviour by default, and you also maintain accssibility standards.

Comment: do you want a link that if you click it that leads to an element on your page?

Answer (score 2):

*My goal is to link it to an anchor (#work1)—a section on my website.*

The real issue is that you misuse terms here. An AI will have trouble figuring out when you misphrase or misuse keywords. An anchor is **not** an ID that you refer to. An anchor simply is a link that you can click on and will direct you to any resource (internal or external).

What you actually want to do is to use an anchor (`<a>`) and assign to the `href` attribute the value of the section ID you want to refer to, starting with the hash (for id).

```css
/* for visualization purpose only */
section {
  min-height: 80vh;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#section-4">click me to go to Section 4</a>

<section id="section-1">Section 1</section>
<section id="section-2">Section 2</section>
<section id="section-3">Section 3</section>
<section id="section-4">Section 4</section>
<section id="section-5">Section 5</section>
```